# "Play it slowly" error (GLib.Error , gconfaudiosink) [not solved]

Tags: 16.04, gstreamer, glib

I recently moved Ubuntu 16.04 from an HDD to SSD.

// latest update: uninstalled, rebooted, reintalled the software. Problem still there.
//

Since then, "Play it slowly" doesn't work, a dialog window goes:

```
An error has occured:
GLib.Error('no element "gconfaudiosink"', 'gst_parse_error', 1)
You should save your work and restart the application. If the error occurs again please report it to the developer.
```

The dialog details:

```
Error
Python 3.5.2: /usr/bin/python3
Fri Apr 14 23:47:25 2017

A problem occurred in a Python script.  Here is the sequence of
function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.

 /usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py in _run_module_as_main(mod_name='playitslowly.app', alter_argv=1)
  182         sys.argv[0] = mod_spec.origin
  183     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  184                      "__main__", mod_spec)
  185 
  186 def run_module(mod_name, init_globals=None,
mod_spec = ModuleSpec(name='playitslowly.app', loader=<_fro...r/lib/python3/dist-packages/playitslowly/app.py')

 /usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py in _run_code(code=<code object <module> at 0xb7140430, file "/usr/...hon3/dist-packages/playitslowly/app.py", line 21>, run_globals={'CONFIG_PATH': '/home/guest/.config/playitslowly.json', 'Config': <class '__main__.Config'>, 'GObject': <GObjectProxyModule <IntrospectionModule 'GObjec...linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/GObject-2.0.typelib'>>, 'Gdk': <GdkProxyModule <IntrospectionModule 'Gdk' from ...386-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/Gdk-3.0.typelib'>>, 'Gio': <GioProxyModule <IntrospectionModule 'Gio' from ...386-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/Gio-2.0.typelib'>>, 'Gst': <GstProxyModule <IntrospectionModule 'Gst' from '/usr/lib/girepository-1.0/Gst-1.0.typelib'>>, 'Gtk': <GtkProxyModule <IntrospectionModule 'Gtk' from ...386-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/Gtk-3.0.typelib'>>, 'MainWindow': <class '__main__.MainWindow'>, 'NAME': 'Play it Slowly', 'Pipeline': <class 'playitslowly.pipeline.Pipeline'>, ...}, init_globals=None, mod_name='__main__', mod_spec=ModuleSpec(name='playitslowly.app', loader=<_fro...r/lib/python3/dist-packages/playitslowly/app.py'), pkg_name='playitslowly', script_name=None)
   83                        __package__ = pkg_name,
   84                        __spec__ = mod_spec)
   85     exec(code, run_globals)
   86     return run_globals
   87 
builtinexec = <built-in function exec>
code = <code object <module> at 0xb7140430, file "/usr/...hon3/dist-packages/playitslowly/app.py", line 21>
run_globals = {'CONFIG_PATH': '/home/guest/.config/playitslowly.json', 'Config': <class '__main__.Config'>, 'GObject': <GObjectProxyModule <IntrospectionModule 'GObjec...linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/GObject-2.0.typelib'>>, 'Gdk': <GdkProxyModule <IntrospectionModule 'Gdk' from ...386-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/Gdk-3.0.typelib'>>, 'Gio': <GioProxyModule <IntrospectionModule 'Gio' from ...386-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/Gio-2.0.typelib'>>, 'Gst': <GstProxyModule <IntrospectionModule 'Gst' from '/usr/lib/girepository-1.0/Gst-1.0.typelib'>>, 'Gtk': <GtkProxyModule <IntrospectionModule 'Gtk' from ...386-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/Gtk-3.0.typelib'>>, 'MainWindow': <class '__main__.MainWindow'>, 'NAME': 'Play it Slowly', 'Pipeline': <class 'playitslowly.pipeline.Pipeline'>, ...}

 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/playitslowly/app.py in <module>()
  529     win.show_all()
  530     Gtk.main()
  531 
  532 if __name__ == "__main__":
  533     main()
main = <function main>

 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/playitslowly/app.py in main()
  520     )
  521 
  522     win = MainWindow(sink, config)
  523 
  524     if arguments:
win undefined
global MainWindow = <class '__main__.MainWindow'>
sink = 'gconfaudiosink'
config = {}

 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/playitslowly/app.py in __init__(self=<__main__.MainWindow object at 0xb3674e64 (__main__+MainWindow at 0x8f1f1e8)>, sink='gconfaudiosink', config={})
  106         self.add_accel_group(self.accel_group)
  107 
  108         self.pipeline = Pipeline(sink)
  109 
  110         self.filedialog = myGtk.FileChooserDialog(None, self, Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN)
self = <__main__.MainWindow object at 0xb3674e64 (__main__+MainWindow at 0x8f1f1e8)>
self.pipeline undefined
global Pipeline = <class 'playitslowly.pipeline.Pipeline'>
sink = 'gconfaudiosink'

 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/playitslowly/pipeline.py in __init__(self=<pipeline.Pipeline object at 0xb367c7d4 (playitslowly+pipeline+Pipeline at 0x91be080)>, sink='gconfaudiosink')
   51         bin.add(self.speedchanger)
   52 
   53         self.audiosink = Gst.parse_launch(sink)
   54         #self.audiosink = Gst.ElementFactory.make(sink, "sink")
   55 
self = <pipeline.Pipeline object at 0xb367c7d4 (playitslowly+pipeline+Pipeline at 0x91be080)>
self.audiosink undefined
global Gst = <GstProxyModule <IntrospectionModule 'Gst' from '/usr/lib/girepository-1.0/Gst-1.0.typelib'>>
Gst.parse_launch = gi.FunctionInfo(parse_launch)
sink = 'gconfaudiosink'
Error: gst_parse_error: no element "gconfaudiosink" (1)
    __cause__ = None
    __class__ = <class 'GLib.GError'>
    __context__ = None
    __delattr__ = <method-wrapper '__delattr__' of Error object>
    __dict__ = {'code': 1, 'domain': 'gst_parse_error', 'message': 'no element "gconfaudiosink"'}
    __dir__ = <built-in method __dir__ of Error object>
    __doc__ = None
    __eq__ = <method-wrapper '__eq__' of Error object>
    __format__ = <built-in method __format__ of Error object>
    __ge__ = <method-wrapper '__ge__' of Error object>
    __getattribute__ = <method-wrapper '__getattribute__' of Error object>
    __gt__ = <method-wrapper '__gt__' of Error object>
    __gtype__ = <GType GError (148212368)>
    __hash__ = <method-wrapper '__hash__' of Error object>
    __init__ = <bound method GError.__init__ of GLib.Error('no element "gconfaudiosink"', 'gst_parse_error', 1)>
    __le__ = <method-wrapper '__le__' of Error object>
    __lt__ = <method-wrapper '__lt__' of Error object>
    __module__ = 'GLib'
    __ne__ = <method-wrapper '__ne__' of Error object>
    __new__ = <built-in method __new__ of type object>
    __reduce__ = <built-in method __reduce__ of Error object>
    __reduce_ex__ = <built-in method __reduce_ex__ of Error object>
    __repr__ = <bound method GError.__repr__ of GLib.Error('no element "gconfaudiosink"', 'gst_parse_error', 1)>
    __setattr__ = <method-wrapper '__setattr__' of Error object>
    __setstate__ = <built-in method __setstate__ of Error object>
    __sizeof__ = <built-in method __sizeof__ of Error object>
    __str__ = <bound method GError.__str__ of GLib.Error('no element "gconfaudiosink"', 'gst_parse_error', 1)>
    __subclasshook__ = <built-in method __subclasshook__ of type object>
    __suppress_context__ = False
    __traceback__ = <traceback object>
    __weakref__ = None
    args = ('no element "gconfaudiosink"',)
    code = 1
    copy = <bound method GError.copy of GLib.Error('no element "gconfaudiosink"', 'gst_parse_error', 1)>
    domain = 'gst_parse_error'
    matches = <bound method gerror_matches of GLib.Error('no element "gconfaudiosink"', 'gst_parse_error', 1)>
    message = 'no element "gconfaudiosink"'
    new_literal = <function gerror_new_literal>
    with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of Error object>

The above is a description of an error in a Python program.  Here is
the original traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/playitslowly/app.py", line 533, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/playitslowly/app.py", line 522, in main
    win = MainWindow(sink, config)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/playitslowly/app.py", line 108, in __init__
    self.pipeline = Pipeline(sink)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/playitslowly/pipeline.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.audiosink = Gst.parse_launch(sink)
GLib.GError: gst_parse_error: no element "gconfaudiosink" (1)
```

When launching from terminal:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/playitslowly/app.py:36: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject, Gst, Gio, Gdk
<class 'GLib.GError'>
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

and after clicking "close" on the dialog, in terminal continues:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/playitslowly/app.py", line 533, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/playitslowly/app.py", line 522, in main
    win = MainWindow(sink, config)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/playitslowly/app.py", line 108, in __init__
    self.pipeline = Pipeline(sink)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/playitslowly/pipeline.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.audiosink = Gst.parse_launch(sink)
GLib.Error: gst_parse_error: no element "gconfaudiosink" (1)
```

I installed and re-installed gstreamer0.10-plugins-good (which contains gstgconfaudiosink) and gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:

```
sudo apt install  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
sudo apt install --reinstall gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
sudo apt install --reinstall gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
```

I still receive the error message when running the software.
(Did a 'sudo apt autoremove' too and rebooted).
Any hints?

Comment: I'm not sure if reinstalling will fix the issue, But anyway ... Use the `--reinstall` switch to make it reinstall: `sudo apt install --reinstall gstreamer0.10-plugins-good`.

Comment: just tried that, no news.

Comment: Take another shot and install this one: `sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-good`. should already be installed, if it is the reinstall it.

Comment: yes, it was already installed. --reinstall...ed: nothing new

Answer (score 1):

Gconfaudiosink is a gstreamer plugin. It is an audio sink used for embedding the GConf-settings for audio output, maybe you are missing it. It is available in the the package gst-plugins, try installing the package.

Comment: edited the question after re-installing the package... problem still open