# How to install gst-plugins? Unable to locate package

Tags: apt, software-installation, plugins, gstreamer

While trying to [get "Play it slowly" back to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903650/play-it-slowly-error-glib-error-gconfaudiosink-not-solved), I need to install Gconfaudiosink, contained in the gst-plugins package.

```
   guest@guest:~$ sudo apt-get install gst-plugins
    [sudo] password for guest: 
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package gst-plugins
```

(same output for gst-plugins-base and gst-plugins-good)

Can you help me installing this plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gst-plugins-*` is somehow an alias or vice versa for the name of the related source packages withing the repositories.

If you search for `Gconfaudiosink` you will reach to this page: [gconfaudiosink](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/gst-plugins-good-plugins-0.10/gst-plugins-good-plugins-gconfaudiosink.html) at [freedesktop.org](http://freedesktop.org), and you will find out that the `gconfaudiosink` should be a part of:
 *GStreamer Good Plugins 0.10*.

Also, if you search in the [gst-plugins-good repository](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/) on [GitHub](http://github.com) for `gconfaudiosink` yo will find out some [commits](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/search?q=gconfaudiosink&type=Commits&utf8=%E2%9C%93) with that names and you will be pretty sure that it's the correct package.

---

To download and install the binary package:

```
sudo apt install  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
```

---

To download the source you can use either of these commands:

*Just to show that `gst-plugins` are avaiable from source.*

```
apt source --download-only gst-plugins-good0.10 

apt source --download-only gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
```

---

I also downloaded the source package to have look around it, and yes, the file you are looking for is there:

```
~/gst-plugins-good0.10-0.10.31/ext/gconf/gstgconfaudiosink.c
```

Comment: Installed the package + autoremove + reboot. You're welcome to come solve the "Play it slowly" back to work question too   https://askubuntu.com/questions/903650/play-it-slowly-error-glib-error-gconfaudiosink